# eclipse Juno often close automatically after ubuntu upgrade to 14.04 TLS

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I was just working with my eclipse before upgrade to 14.04.But After upgrade to 14.04 , my eclipse close often without any warning message.And it generate a hs_err_pid4612.log file in my desktop. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem - crashes randomly without any error....

Comment: Please have a look in my answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add following line at the end of your eclipse.ini file .(eclipse.ini file is located in eclipse folder of eclipse package.)

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

Comment: but,it is not useful for me.help me

Answer (score 0):

I am using eclipse juno with ubuntu 14.04 and I had the same problem.
Adding the line to the ini file did not work for me.
What I did to solve the problem is changing the JRE from 1.7 to 1.6 in the project properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

This worked for me.