# eclipse Juno often close automatically on ubuntu 14.04 TLS

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, eclipse-juno

I am facing this problem from last week, I apply all solutions on SO but didn't work in my case. How to resolve this problem.

Comment: could you post your error in eclipse?., I used to work on eclipse but I switched to Intellij then now I'm using Android Studio. May be you could consider this IDE. They are working well in my ubuntu 14.04 lts.

Comment: @chkm8, actually this is not an error but after closing log.txt file show following lines....

Comment: !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-11-11 12:21:44.492
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

Comment: have you tried to use a fresh copy of your eclipse, maybe that copy somehow corrupted due to force closed or some error.

Comment: @chkm8, No, but now I am using Android studio and It works fine....

Answer (score 0):

I thinks your answer may be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198322/eclipse-juno-often-close-automaticaly-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-14-04-tls) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836396/eclipse-juno-new-version-of-adt-always-crashes-in-ubuntu-14-04-and-create-an-e).

I addedd the following lines at the end of the eclipse.ini file .(eclipse.ini file is located in eclipse folder of eclipse package.)

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

And it works for me!